# Что делает данный код в typescript?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, nextjs

Не могу понять код из фреймворка nextjs

```
export type NextPage<P = {}, IP = P> =
```

Т.е. мы создаем тип у которого первый аргумент будет {}, а второй равен первому?

не понимаю что значит выражение в <>

Comment: [typescript: generics](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html)

Comment: Почитал но все равно не пойму что значит IP = P , установка значения IP по умолчанию равном P ?

Comment: Да, если вручную не задаешь значения, то по умолчанию в этом случае будет `<{},{}>` если не задашь оба и если не задашь один `<Type, Type>`

Comment: https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/PTAEnwQQBEEPhBEEQQhEGqQ-CCUBwggeEEKwgkBQBTADwAcB7AJwBdRKBPY-UAOSMoAUBDAc3wB43QAXlABvAL4AaUAEkBwtgD4hoANqg2U2aAC6AblwESFanQagAdqQCC5LgGdlLQu275doEKHhpkq8VPE9QzIqGnpGUnN8Gy5HVk4eXnMAVwBbACN8cgV3T29fFRSMrKkizPIgohCTcJoAd2tbB2EnF0S7SnIAS3MuKXTSUgAbfA5zHI8wfNUO7t7+wZGxvSA